# Return false does not allow echo

Tags: php

Following is my code in which i am facing only one difficulty that when i run the following script then due to comparison failure the $flag doesnot echo kindly let me know how to fix this?

```
$s = "iph4on comes";
$se = "4gb comes in iphone";
$f = 0;

$tf = explode(" ",$searching);
$ms= explode(" ",$search_in);
foreach($tf as $word)
{
if (!preg_match("/$word/i", $search_in))
//if (!strpos($search_in, $word));
return false;
}
{
$f = 1;
}
echo $f;

//Due to return flase above i am not echoing
echo "Comparison Failed";
```

Comment: No code will run beyond a return, that is correct. Fix: put code you want to run _before_ return, or reflow the code so that the return happens afterwards.

Comment: If this is inside a function, please post the whole thing. It makes little sense as it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`return` terminates the currently executing code block and "returns" to whatever called that code. if you execute a return in the top level of the code, it's essentially an `exit()` call and your echo will never be reached.

Comment: then what is another good way to set flag in the above code which i can use to echo accordingly??

Answer (score 0):

Why not just put an `echo $flag` before the return statement?

```
if (!preg_match("/$word/i", $search_in)){
  echo $flag
  return false;
}
```

Comment: I would have to agree here, as return terminates the script at that point therefore any code afterwards will be simply ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the `echo` before the `return`. `return` gets the execution back to the calling function, hence any code after that won't be executed.

```
 if (!preg_match("/$word/i", $search_in)) {
  $flag = 1;
  echo $flag;
  echo "Comparison Failed"; 
  return false;
 }
```